# State change after a certain amount of time with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a certain variable that is being toggled between false and true as a state (we can call it submitted).   What I would like to do is have the state change back to false after it has been set to true, after a few seconds.  How would I do this?

I have this function that is called when a button is clicked, and where the state changes:

```
saveAndContinue: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if(this.state.submitted==false) {
        email = this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value
        this.setState({email: email})
        this.setState({submitted: !this.state.submitted});

    }

  }
```

I would like to add to this, where I have a timer set the variable submitted back to false.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 21):

You can set a timeout to reset the state after a given amount of time. Remember to `bind(this)` to the timeout function so that `this` refers to the right `this`

```
saveAndContinue: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if(this.state.submitted==false) {
        email = this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value
        this.setState({email: email})
        this.setState({submitted: !this.state.submitted});
        setTimeout(function(){
             this.setState({submitted:false});
        }.bind(this),5000);  // wait 5 seconds, then reset to false
   }
}
```

Comment: At time of writing, arrow functions are much more popular and retain the `this` binding.